# How to remove <br> tags from short description programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I am using Magento 2.3.1

I have 8000 products which are migrated from Magento 1. The issue is that the 
 tags are added in short and long description in Magento 2. Please see below content for reference:
[image]

This is how short description looks like in the front end. Below content is added in the product in admin:

```
This is the short description migrated from Magento 1<br><br>short description<br><br>• This is the point 1<br>• This is the point 2<br>• This is the point 3<br>• This is the point 4<br>• This is the point 5<br>•<b>This is the point 6</b>
```

I have used the below code:

```
<?php 
  $short_description = strip_tags( $short_description, 'li' );
  $short_description = "<ul><li>" . preg_replace( '/[\r\n]+/', '</li><li>', 
  $short_description ) . "</li></ul>";
  $short_description = str_replace('<li></li>', '', $short_description ); 
?>
<?= $short_description ?>
```

But the whole content is displayed in one `<li>` tag after implementing the above code.

Now I want to add each bullet points in `<li>` tags and also I want to remove `<br>` tag from the content as well. how can I do this?

Comment: why are you remove `<ul>` `<li>` & `<br>` tag? If you are using editor in admin then you can get save formate value in frontend using function. `$block->filterOutputHtml('yout field_name')`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$short_description= "This is the short description migrated from Magento 1<br><br>short description<br><br>• This is the point 1<br>• This is the point 2<br>• This is the point 3<br>• This is the point 4<br>• This is the point 5<br>•<b>This is the point 6</b>";
$strArray = explode('•',$short_description);
$newShortDescription = strip_tags($strArray[0]);
$newShortDescription .="<ul>";
for($i=1; $i<count($strArray);$i++){
    $newShortDescription .="<li>".strip_tags($strArray[$i])."</li>";
}
$newShortDescription .="</ul>";
?>
<?= $newShortDescription ?>
```